# References cannot be found after pulling down code from TFS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, reference

I have a .NET Web Application, and I include some 3rd party references in a folder called references. That folder is in the same directory as the Visual Studios solution, but not the same directory as the Project File. Now, when I first create this project, add my references, and build - everything works perfectly. However - once I check in to TFS and then try pulling down the code, the references cannot be found. They still exist in the "references" folder that I created, but they are not showing up in the bin folder. Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this? I'm using Visual Studios 2012.

Comment: The most correct answer is to use NuGet to manage binary dependencies instead of source control.

Comment: I'm working with Ektron and I don't believe I can use NuGet to include their dlls.

Comment: You can set up an on-premise NuGet server and put anything you want in there.

Comment: you could create your own nuget package and host it locally

Answer (score 2):

When you checkin to TFS, make sure you checkin those DLLs. By default, TFS excludes binary files during checkin.

[image]

Also, if those 3rd party Dlls are hosted on Nuget, then use Nuget packages to add/manage references. That way, you do not have to bother checkin them into TFS. You can simply enable Nuget's package restore on build (right click on Solution -> Enable Nuget Package Restore). More info [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

Comment: I do in fact check in these DLLS, but for whatever reason, whenever I check in to TFS and then get the code and remap to a new folder, the project still cannot find those DLLs, even though they exist in the folder they were created in. If I add those dlls to the bin folder, then it can find the references.

Comment: Are the paths to the assemblies relative, or absolute?

Comment: then your references are wrong, you need to reference the dll's from the references folder, as part of the build they will then be pulled into the bin folder. nothing in the bin folder will or Should be checked in to TFS

Comment: Looks like a reference path issue then. Check your csproj file and see if the references are added using relative or absolute path and whether the path matches to what you're expecting.

Comment: I think you would probably be right - they look to be relative, but you're correct - they didn't seem 100% accurate. Should I really have to update all the paths for all my references?

Comment: I would say sanitize them once and ensure they are mapped to the references folder (not bin). Sometimes, VS can mess up the path so its better to start with a clean slate and see if it still happens.